# I can't seem to use the Bash "-c" option with arguments after the "-c" option string

Tags: bash, eval

The man page for Bash says, regarding the `-c` option:

> `-c string`
>   If the `-c` option is present, then commands are read from
>   *`string`*. If there are arguments after
>   the string, they are assigned to the
>   positional parameters, starting with
>   `$0`.

So given that description, I would think something like this ought to work:

```
bash -c "echo arg 0: $0, arg 1: $1" arg1
```

but the output just shows the following, so it looks like the arguments after the `-c` string are not being assigned to the positional parameters.

```
arg 0: -bash, arg 1:
```

I am running a fairly ancient Bash (on Fedora 4):

> [root@dd42 trunk]# bash --version
>   GNU bash, version 3.00.16(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)
>   Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

I am really trying to execute a bit of a shell script with arguments. I thought `-c` looked very promising, hence the issue above. I wondered about using eval, but I don't think I can pass arguments to the stuff that follows eval. I'm open to other suggestions as well.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to use single quotes to prevent interpolation happening in your calling shell.

```
$ bash -c 'echo arg 0: $0, arg 1: $1' arg1 arg2
arg 0: arg1, arg 1: arg2
```

Or escape the variables in your double-quoted string.  Which to use might depend on exactly what you want to put in your snippet of code.

Comment: note that a "$@" inside -c will skip "$0" (the name of the shell) so in this case you might want to pass arguments like `bash -c '...' $0 arg1 arg2`

Comment: @geekley finally! gave me the clue to passing all of $@ to a script run with -c (which i needed to do in a login shell for other reasons).  So in my case like this.  `/bin/bash -l -c '${SCRIPTS_DIR}/start.sh $@' $0 "$@"`.  In a way -c will script $1 for $@ so add it back with $0.  That was not obvious.

Answer (score 6):

Because '`$0`' and '`$1`' in your string is replaced with a variable #0 and #1 respectively.

Try :

```
bash -c "echo arg 0: \$0, arg 1: \$1" arg0 arg1
```

In this code `$` of both are escape so base see it as a string `$` and not get replaced.

The result of this command is:

```
arg 0: arg0, arg 1: arg1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

martin is right about the interpolation: you need to use single quotes. But note that if you're trying to pass arguments to a command that is being executed *within* the string, you need to forward them on explicitly. For example, if you have a script *foo.sh* like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 0:$0
echo 1:$1
echo 2:$2
```

Then you should **call it like this**:

```
$ bash -c './foo.sh ${1+"$@"}' foo "bar baz"
0:./foo.sh
1:bar baz
2:
```

Or more generally `bash -c '${0} ${1+"$@"}' <command> [argument]...`

[Not like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144519/45630):

```
$ bash -c ./foo.sh foo "bar baz"
0:./foo.sh
1:
2:
```

[Nor like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/743577/320036):

```
$ bash -c './foo.sh $@' foo "bar baz"
0:./foo.sh
1:bar
2:baz
```

This means you can pass in arguments to sub-processes without embedding them in the command string, and without worrying about escaping them.

Answer (score 2):

Add a backslash to the `$0` (i.e., `\$0`), otherwise your current shell escapes `$0` to the name of the shell before it even gets to the subshell.