# Concatenate all arguments and wrap them with double quotes

Tags: string, bash, shell, concatenation

```
function foo() {
A=$@...
echo $A
}

foo bla "hello ppl"
```

I would like the output to be:
"bla" "hello ppl"

What do I need to do instead of the ellipsis?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is the output of `foo` to be used as input to anything or do you just want the raw text?

Comment: It's supposed to be used as input for another command (mail in this case).

Comment: @rubim: then I think you are making it much harder than it need be. `mail "$@"` would give the results without the un-parse / re-parse step. If `"$@"` isn't in the proper state, please show what you do have.

Answer (score 26):

@msw has the right idea (up in the comments on the question).  However, another idea to print arguments with quotes: use the implicit iteration of `printf`:

```
foo() { printf '"%s" ' "$@"; echo ""; }

foo bla "hello ppl"
# => "bla" "hello ppl"
```

Comment: Ding! You win the big prize. Giant teddy bear or four-foot beer-bottle coin bank?

Comment: Why did you add echo ""; at the end? Isn't it unnecessary.

Comment: So the output would end with a newline. Just so it looks nice and doesn't mess up your prompt. I realize it's unnecessary when called with a command substitution

Comment: Thanks it works great. To bad there isn't a simple, one liner, bash version of this.

Comment: uh, didn't  I provide a "simple one liner"?

Comment: By simple I meant pure bash variable substitution. Sort of like what FGM did bellow, but one liner not a function.

Comment: `foo bla 'hello" "ppl'` ?

Comment: It misses an escape function to be exact. `foo "a\\bc"` results in `foo "a\bc"`

Answer (score 6):

Use parameter substitution to add " as prefix and suffix:

```
function foo() {
    A=("${@/#/\"}")
    A=("${A[@]/%/\"}")
    echo -e "${A[@]}"
}

foo bla "hello ppl" kkk 'ss ss'
```

Output

```
"bla" "hello ppl" "kkk" "ss ss"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use "$@" to treat each parameter as, well, a separate parameter, and then loop over each parameter:

```
function foo() {
for i in "$@"
do
    echo -n \"$i\"" "
done
echo
}

foo bla "hello ppl"
```

Comment: +1 This solution works! I am lazy, so I usually drop the 'in "$@"' part and only use 'for i'

Comment: I forgot to mention this in the question but I meant to do this without using a loop. Was looking for some magic bash expansion or something.

Answer (score 3):

ninjalj had the right idea, but the use of quotes was odd, in part because what the OP is asking for is not really the best output format for many shell tasks. Actually, I can't figure out what the intended task is, but:

```
function quote_args {
   for i ; do
      echo \""$i"\"
   done
}
```

puts its quoted arguments one per line which is usually the best way to feed other programs. You do get output in a form you didn't ask for:

```
$ quote_args this is\ a "test really"
"this"
"is a"
"test really"
```

but it can be easily converted and this is the idiom that most shell invocations would prefer:

```
$ echo `quote_args this is\ a "test really"`
"this" "is a" "test really"
```

but unless it is going through another `eval` pass, the extra quotes will probably screw things up. That is, `ls "is a file"` will list the file `is a file` while

```
$ ls `quote_args is\ a\ file`
```

will try to list `"is`,  `a`, and `file"` which you probably don't want.

Answer (score 2):

No loop required:

```
foo() { local saveIFS=$IFS; local IFS='"'; local a="${*/#/ \"}"; echo "$a"\"; IFS=$saveIFS; }
```

Saving `IFS` isn't necessary in this simple example, especially restoring it right before the function exits, due to the fact that `local` is used. However, I included it in case other things are going into the function that a changed `IFS` might affect.

Example run:

```
$ foo a bcd "efg hij" k "lll mmm nnn " ooo "   ppp   qqq   " rrr\ sss
 "a" "bcd" "efg hij" "k" "lll mmm nnn " "ooo" "   ppp   qqq   " "rrr sss"
```

Answer (score 1):

The only solution at this time that respects backslashes and quotes inside the argument:

```
$ concatenate() { printf "%q"" " "$@"; echo ""; }
$ concatenate arg1 "arg2" "weird arg3\\\\\\bbut\" legal!"
arg1 arg2 weird\ arg3\\\\\\bbut\"\ legal\!
```

Notice the **"%q"" "**

> **%q**     ARGUMENT  is  printed  in  a format that can be reused as shell
>   input, escaping non-printable characters with the
>                 proposed POSIX $'' syntax.

Special characters (`\`, `\b` backspace, ...) will indeed be interpreted by the receiving program, even if not displayed interpreted in the terminal output.

Let's test:

```
# display.sh: Basic script to display the first 3 arguments passed
echo -e '#!/bin/bash'"\n"'echo -e "\$1=""$1"; echo -e "\$2=""$2"; echo -e "\$3=""$3"; sleep 2;' > display.sh
sudo chmod 755 display.sh

# Function to concatenate arguments as $ARGS
# and "evalutate" the command display.sh $ARGS
test_bash() { ARGS=$(concatenate "$@"); bash -c "./display.sh ""$ARGS"; }

# Test: Output is identical whatever the special characters
./display.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
test_bash    arg1 arg2 arg3
```

More complicate test:

```
./display.sh arg1 "arg2-1:Y\b-2:Y\\b-3:Y\\\b-4:Y\\\\b-5:Y\\\\\b-6:Y\\\\\\b" "arg3-XY\bZ-\"-1:\-2:\\-3:\\\-4:\\\\-5:\\\\\-6:\\\\\\-"
test_bash    arg1 "arg2-1:Y\b-2:Y\\b-3:Y\\\b-4:Y\\\\b-5:Y\\\\\b-6:Y\\\\\\b" "arg3-XY\bZ-\"-1:\-2:\\-3:\\\-4:\\\\-5:\\\\\-6:\\\\\\-"
```

In `display.sh`, we are using `echo -e` instead of just `echo` or `printf` in order to interpret the special characters. This is only representative if your called program interprets them.

> **-e**     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
>
> If -e is in effect, the following sequences are recognized:
>
> - \     backslash
> - \a     alert (BEL)
> - \b     backspace
> - Etc.

NB: `\b` is the backspace character, so it erases Y in the example.

Note that this example is not to be reproduced in real code:

- It is very uncommon to concatenate arguments, always use [positional parameter](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams) when possible.
- `bash -c` and `screen -X` DO accept several arguments so there's no need to use concatenation: see [Can't seem to use bash -c option with arguments after the -c option string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711970/2227298)). Just beware of passing something for `$0` when using `bash -c`.

*Thanks to the accepted answer and [Danny Hong answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13143174/2227298) in "How to escape double quote inside a double quote?"*