# How can I escape a double quote inside double quotes?

Tags: bash, quotes

How can I escape double quotes inside a double string in Bash?

For example, in my shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

dbload="load data local infile \"'gfpoint.csv'\" into table $dbtable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY \"'\n'\" IGNORE 1 LINES"
```

I can't get the `ENCLOSED BY '\"'` with double quote to escape correctly. I can't use single quotes for my variable, because I want to use variable `$dbtable`.

Comment: Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping single-quotes within single-quoted strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/escaping-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings)

Comment: @kenorb Doesn't look like a duplicate of that question...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: @Daenyth This isn't the type of command you'd expect end users to have any access to. Bulk load scripts are usually run *on* the server by trusted users (such as system admins or developers). Yes, if end users control the value of `$dbtable`, there's a risk. This would be *very* uncommon, though, as end users don't typically SSH into a machine to load their data.

Comment: @jpmc26 Malicious input isn't the only case - loading from a csv could easily include data that's invalid sql just by accident.

Comment: @Daenyth The CSV is never parsed as SQL.... It's parsed by an explicit [CSV parsing command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) that inserts the values into a table.

Comment: See also: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).

Comment: The canonical for single quotes:  *[How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/)*

Answer (score 390):

Use a backslash:

```
echo "\""     # Prints one " character.
```

Comment: Not working. `x=ls; if [ -f "$(which "\""$x"\"")" ]; then echo exists; else echo broken; fi;` gives broken whereas `... [ -f "$(which $x)" ]; ...` or `... [ -f $(which "$x") ]; ...` work just fine. Issues would arise when either `$x` or the result of `$(which "$x")` gives anything with a space or other special character. A workaround is using a variable to hold the result of `which`, but is bash really incapable of escaping a quote or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am trying to use the following `grep -oh "\"\""$counter"\""\w*" ` as part of a bash syntax where in `$counter` is a variable. it doesn't like it any thoughts

Comment: @AndroidEngineX, this method works fine when used correctly. Luc's comment above is using it wrong; they're telling `which` to search for an executable that has literal quotes in its name, and of course no such thing exists. That's Luc's own problem, not a mistake with this answer.

Comment: @JayD, `\w` doesn't work in POSIX-standard `grep` at all in the first place. It's a PCRE extension, and grep only supports BRE and ERE. I couldn't evaluate your comment more than that without knowing what strings you expect to match / how you're testing.

Answer (score 147):

A simple example of escaping quotes in the shell:

```
$ echo 'abc'\''abc'
abc'abc
$ echo "abc"\""abc"
abc"abc
```

It's done by finishing an already-opened one (`'`), placing the escaped one (`\'`), and then opening another one (`'`).

Alternatively:

```
$ echo 'abc'"'"'abc'
abc'abc
$ echo "abc"'"'"abc"
abc"abc
```

It's done by finishing already opened one (`'`), placing a quote in another quote (`"'"`), and then opening another one (`'`).

More examples: [Escaping single-quotes within single-quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1250079/55075)

Comment: I tried sh -c "echo '{"key":"value"}'" and even sh -c "echo '{''"''key''"'':''"''value''"''}'" in an effort to enclose the words key and value in double quotes, but in both cases I got {key:value}

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated for double quotes: `echo "abc\"abc"` is sufficient to produce `abc"abc` as in Peter answer.

Comment: In this simple example indeed, but in complex cases of nested quotes, it can be necessary to do this and @kenorb's example helped me figure out how to deal with those cases.

Answer (score 93):

Keep in mind that you can avoid escaping by using ASCII codes of the characters you need to echo.

Example:

```
echo -e "This is \x22\x27\x22\x27\x22text\x22\x27\x22\x27\x22"
This is "'"'"text"'"'"
```

`\x22` is the ASCII code (in hex) for double quotes and `\x27` for single quotes. Similarly you can echo any character.

I suppose if we try to echo the above string with backslashes, we will need a messy two rows backslashed echo... :)

For variable assignment this is the equivalent:

```
a=$'This is \x22text\x22'
echo "$a"

# Output:
This is "text"
```

If the variable is already set by another program, you can still apply double/single quotes with sed or similar tools.

Example:

```
b="Just another text here"
echo "$b"

 Just another text here

sed 's/text/"'\0'"/' <<<"$b" #\0 is a special sed operator
 Just another "0" here #this is not what i wanted to be

sed 's/text/\x22\x27\0\x27\x22/' <<<"$b"

 Just another "'text'" here #now we are talking. You would normally need a dozen of backslashes to achieve the same result in the normal way.
```

Comment: +1 because it solved a problem of adding a PS1 variable to ~/.profile


`echo 'export PS1='\[\033[00;31m\]${?##0}$([ $? -ne 0 ] && echo \x22 \x22)\[\033[00;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]@\[\033[00;36m\]\h\[\033[00m\][\[\033[01;33m\]\d \t\[\033[00m\]] \[\033[01;34m\]\w\n\[\033[00m\]$( [ ${EUID} -ne 0 ] && echo \x22$\x22 || echo \x22#\x22 ) '' >> ~/.profile`

Comment: This is THE answer! I love u Sir.

Answer (score 37):

Bash allows you to place strings adjacently, and they'll just end up being glued together.

So this:

```
echo "Hello"', world!'
```

produces

```
Hello, world!
```

The trick is to alternate between single and double-quoted strings as required. Unfortunately, it quickly gets very messy. For example:

```bash
echo "I like to use" '"double quotes"' "sometimes"
```

produces

```
I like to use "double quotes" sometimes
```

---

In your example, I would do it something like this:

```bash
dbtable=example
dbload='load data local infile "'"'gfpoint.csv'"'" into '"table $dbtable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'"'"' LINES "'TERMINATED BY "'"'\n'"'" IGNORE 1 LINES'
echo $dbload
```

which produces the following output:

```
load data local infile "'gfpoint.csv'" into table example FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY "'\n'" IGNORE 1 LINES
```

---

It's difficult to see what's going on here, but I can annotate it using Unicode quotes. The following won't work in Bash – it's just for illustration:

`dbload=`‘`load data local infile "`’“`'gfpoint.csv'`”‘`" into` ’“`table $dbtable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '`”‘`"`’“`' LINES` ”‘`TERMINATED BY "`’“`'\n'`”‘`" IGNORE 1 LINES`’

The quotes like “ ‘ ’ ” in the above will be interpreted by bash. The quotes like `" '` will end up in the resulting variable.

If I give the same treatment to the earlier example, it looks like this:

`echo` “`I like to use`” ‘`"double quotes"`’ “`sometimes`”

Comment: a subtlety of my second `echo` example, that I've not bothered to explain, is that here I'm actually giving echo three separate arguments, because the strings aren't touching. but the `echo` command prints all three, separated by spaces, so it sort of does what you'd expect. The difference is, if you type `echo a     b     c` it will output `a b c`, whereas if you type `echo 'a     b     c'` it will print `a     b     c`.

Answer (score 34):

Store the double quote character in a variable:

```
dqt='"'
echo "Double quotes ${dqt}X${dqt} inside a double quoted string"
```

Output:

```
Double quotes "X" inside a double quoted string
```

Comment: Bash truly is the worst language

Comment: @12oclocker, your answer is foolproof :D! specially when using with "sed" command it saved my day!

Answer (score 20):

Check out **printf**...

```
#!/bin/bash
mystr="say \"hi\""
```

Without using printf

```
echo -e $mystr
```

Output: say "hi"

Using **printf**

```
echo -e $(printf '%q' $mystr)
```

Output: say \"hi\"

Comment: Note that `printf` escapes more characters as well, such as `'`, `(` and `)`

Comment: `printf %q` generates strings ready for `eval`, not formatted for `echo -e`.

Comment: There is no reason to wrap the `printf` with a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo).  Both your examples have broken quoting.  The proper fix is to double-quote the variable.

Answer (score 12):

Make use of $"string".

In this example, it would be,

```
dbload=$"load data local infile \"'gfpoint.csv'\" into table $dbtable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY \"'\n'\" IGNORE 1 LINES"
```

Note (from the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)):

> A double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign ($"string") will cause the string to be translated according to the current locale. If the current locale is C or POSIX, the dollar sign is ignored. If the string is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.

Comment: Nice, didn't know that one.

Answer (score 1):

For use with variables that might contain spaces in you Bash script, use **triple quotes** inside the main quote, e.g.:

```
[ "$(date -r """$touchfile""" +%Y%m%d)" -eq "$(date +%Y%m%d)" ]
```

Comment: Triple quotes have no special meaning in bash: two of the quotes cancel each other out, leaving only the third; making the behavior 100% identical to just using only one quote. (`$( )` creates a new quoting context, so you don't **need** to escape double quotes inside it at all in the first place; it's only backticks that have a problem there).

Comment: Try it yourself: `[ "$(date -r "$touchfile" +%Y%m%d)" -eq "$(date +%Y%m%d)" ]` works exactly the same way as the code suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about use `echo`.

For example,

```
x=$(echo \"a b c\")
```

To use the variable,

```
echo $x && ls "$x"
```

The reason I prefer echo rather than printf is that it's more straightforward.

Answer (score -10):

Add `"\"` before double quote to escape it, instead of `\`

```
#! /bin/csh -f

set dbtable = balabala

set dbload = "load data local infile "\""'gfpoint.csv'"\"" into table $dbtable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"\""' LINES TERMINATED BY "\""'\n'"\"" IGNORE 1 LINES"

echo $dbload
# load data local infile "'gfpoint.csv'" into table balabala FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY "''" IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Comment: Downvote: Why are you posting a `csh` answer to a `bash` question?  The two are completely distinct and incompatible.