# can't use postgresql function in bash script

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql, ubuntu, postgis

I am new to postgresql and I'm using postgresql 9.3 and postgis 2.1.

In pgadmin, I am able to use a function in database "AddGeometryColumn", but when I write that script in Ubuntu bash, it doesn't work. The error I got is

```
ERROR:  function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AddGeometryColumn('tiger_staging','al_place','the_geo...
           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Does anyone have similar experience?

Also how do you specify "use" database in postgresql? like a query in mysql "use mydatabase" to switch database?

Comment: please, post the code that gives the error

Comment: The code is generated from tiger_geocoder in postgis 2.1, so it should be same as everyone used to load Tiger database.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using "psql", so do just like this:

```
psql [databasename] -U [username] -t -e --command="select [function]"
```

As "Hint" says, you need to cast your param values with exact same types of your function's parameters:

```
psql [databasename] -U [username] -t -e --command="SELECT AddGeometryColumn(cast('tiger_staging' as character varying),..."
```

Also check if the number of params in your select matchs your function's parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably connected to a database that does not have the PostGIS extension installed (e.g. the default `postgres` database). In `psql` (the command-line client), check that the name coming before the `=#` prompt matches the database you want to use:

```
postgres=#
```

To switch to another database, use the `\c` command:

```
postgres=# \c mydatabase
```

...
    mydatabase=#

To check that the PostGIS extension is correctly installed in your current DB, use the `postgis_full_version()` function:

```
SELECT postgis_full_version();
```

This should return information on the PostGIS version if the extension is enabled. If you get a `No function matches the given name and argument types` error, you will need to install the extension in your current DB:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Note that the PostGIS package has to be installed in order to be able to enable the extension in a database.

Answer (score 0):

You are tripping over **CaMeL case names**.

Identifier (like `AddGeometryColumn`) are folded to lower case (`addgeometrycolumn`) unless double-quoted (**`"AddGeometryColumn"`**). [Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)
Unfortunately, PostGis functions follow a naming convention that requires double-quoting at all times.

For your bash-invocation, you probably need to use single quotes around your string to remove the special meaning of double-quotes. [Or escape with backslash (`\"`).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834839/escaping-double-quote-inside-a-double-quote)

Where ever I can I stick to legal, lower-case names exclusively for all identifiers to prevent problems like the one at hand.

Comment: Most of the PostGIS functions are documented as camel case, but operate as lower case names. Some were even renamed to fit this style, e.g. `ST_Line_Locate_Point` was recently renamed `ST_LineLocatePoint`

Comment: @MikeToews: Well, I keep seeing desperate questions like the one above which reinforces my standing advice: only use *legal, lower case identifiers* that don't have to be double-quoted and save yourself some headache. The PostGis people probably have their reasons. Maybe some geo-data cross-platform compliance? I never use CaMeL case names if I can avoid it. I clarified the answer: legal to use, but my advice is to avoid them.

Comment: I generally agree to use sane names. The "ST_CamelCase" convention used by most spatial databases started in the OGC and SQL/MM standards.