# Sqoop psql query with dates

Tags: mysql, postgresql, hadoop, sqoop

Hi I have issues querying with swoop and a psaldb

```
     Sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:postgresql://xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxxx/database' --query 'select * from report where transact_time = '20160603-00:00:01' and $CONDITIONS' --username uname --target-dir /user/x/data --split-by transact_time
```

I get the following error :

```
  Error executing statement: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
  Position: 61
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
```

Comment: Seems like a quoting issue: `... 'select ... transact_time = '20160603-00:00:01' ... ' ...` (and also, it doesn't seem like a timestamp at all)

Comment: I tried many combinations of quotes. None work

Comment: If that's in a command line I would try `--query "select ... 'quoted values' ..."` first, and if that's not working somehow, use [escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834839/how-to-escape-double-quote-inside-a-double-quote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to issue the query wrapped with double quotes (`"`) as you are using single quotes (`'`) in the query and you will have to use `\$CONDITIONS` instead of just `$CONDITIONS` to disallow your shell from treating it as a shell variable.

Try:

```
--query "select * from report where transact_time = '20160603-00:00:01' and \$CONDITIONS"
```

Comment: Thanks yes this is exactly what I ended up doing and it worked.