# AWS Run Command (ssm send-command) Runs Scripts Wrong

Tags: amazon-web-services, bamboo, aws-ssm

I asked a while ago: [AWS Run Command act different than running on server locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765769/aws-run-command-act-different-than-running-on-server-locally)

Why does AWS Run Command act so different than normal operations. It does very strange things.

For instance:

I run a send-command from my Bamboo Server, to my EC2, then once my EC2 is finished, it sends another send-command back to my Bamboo Server
This Fails... the send command never reaches my Bamboo Server

Now I can run that same batch file manually on my EC2, it does it's thing, then sends the other ssm send-command back to other EC2. No problem.

What is so different? I have full permissions. I don't see any log errors or anything.

Another thing:
My batch file always runs in the background... is this why I'm getting weird results from the aforementioned problem? Why does it always run my apps/exe in the background?

Any insight would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Super old question so you've probably moved on from it already but I guess try to isolate it by sending a simple touch command between each server and then verify that you see the created file in both directions. Once that's there then you know it's not a permission issue or whatever else. I've had issues in sending too many SSM Send-Commands to the same server and they started python scripts that took a long time to finish and my SSM Send-Commands appeared to be being queued and only 3 of them would run at any given time...

Comment: @KyleBridenstine man, I remember this. I believe my problem occurred when I called powershell scripts from bat files. The return value on the process had to be NULL... or something like that. If not NULL, then the bat file couldn't exit properly when running a subsequent process. This does not occur when running it manually because the cmd line handles the bat file a little differently.