# Linux find and replace: how to escape single quotes in strings?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

Total newbee on this, so here's what is not working:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/\$_SESSION['valOne']"/\$valTwo,"/g' {} +
```

While it should replace recursively, in all the directories it is going through:

```
$_SESSION['valOne'] into just: $valTwo
```

I've done this many times, but it seems the quotes are too confusing for me.
Any help here is highly appreciated.

Comment: Add `\ ` before quote. `\'` should work

Comment: I thought that as well, but it doesn't update the text in the file(s). Any other reason why this can happen?

Comment: it actually gives me the > on the command line

Comment: Just wondering....why you don't change it via IDE? :)

Comment: Instead of escaping use `\x22` for double quotes or `\x27` for single quotes - See this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834839/how-to-escape-double-quote-inside-a-double-quote/42341860#42341860

Comment: @george Vaciliou: tried that and didn't work. The solution for this one is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try as follows. Change the **'** -> **"** and escape with the backslash.

Example:

```
 find . -type f -exec sed -i "s/\$_SESSION\['valOne'\]/\$valTwo/g" {} +
```

Comment: Thanks, but sorry. The command is ok, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: I made it based on your regex. Make sure that `quotes` after `$_SESSION` exists in the php file. Remove the first `\"` and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is actually this one, but it works perfect now: find . -type f -exec sed -i "s/\$_SESSION\['valOne'\]/\$valTwo/g" {} +

Comment: please change your answer so I can vote for it and people see the right answer

Comment: No. Always use single quotes unless you NEED double quotes (e.g. to expand a variable) and then use double quotes unless you NEED no quotes (e.g. for globbing). In this case using double quotes around the string is exposing it to the shell for interpretation so you're then having to escape the `$`s so the shell doesn't try to expand the subsequent text as if it was a variable. Just don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying do do (literal replacements) then you need to single quote the string so the shell doesn't try to interpret its contents, then use `'\''` for each singe quote within the string and escape any BRE metacharacters (i.e. `[` and `]` in your case):

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/$_SESSION\['\''valOne'\''\]"/$valTwo,"/g' {} +
```