# elasticsearch duplicate documents multi fields search error

Tags: elasticsearch

This search of duplicate documents for single field is working.
The index is test_4. The type is test_4. The field is date.

```
curl -XGET 'http://ip:9200/test_4/test_4/_search?pretty=true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
      "field": "date.keyword",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

This search of duplicate documents for multi fields is not working. The index is test_4. The type is test_4. The fields are date and EventType.

```
curl -XGET 'http://ip:9200/test_4/test_4/_search?pretty=true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
      "script": "doc['"'"'date'"'"'].values + doc['"'"'EventType'"'"'].values",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

This is the error.

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

This search of duplicate documents for multi fields is not working. The index is test_4. The type is test_4. The fields are date and EventType.

```
curl -XGET 'http://ip:9200/test_4/test_4/_search?pretty=true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
      "script": "def l = []; l.addAll(doc['date']); l.addAll(doc['EventType'].values); l",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

This is the error.

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

This search of duplicate documents for multi fields is not working. The index is test_4. The type is test_4. The fields are date and EventType.

```
curl -XGET 'http://ip:9200/test_4/test_4/_search?pretty=true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
      "script": "def l = []; l.addAll(doc['"'"'date'"'"']); l.addAll(doc['"'"'EventType'"'"'].values); l",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

This is the error.

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

This search of duplicate documents for multi fields is not working.
The index is test_4. The type is test_4. The fields are date and EventType.

```
curl -XGET 'http://ip:9200/test_4/test_4/_search?pretty=true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
      "script": "doc['date'].values + doc['EventType'].values",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

This is the error.
The error reason is "Variable [date] is not defined".

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "script_exception",
        "reason" : "compile error",
        "script_stack" : [
          "doc[date].values + doc[EventT ...",
          "    ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script" : "doc[date].values + doc[EventType].values",
        "lang" : "painless"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "test_4",
        "node" : "dhB-H0_yRROhoP6W-FhOyA",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "script_exception",
          "reason" : "compile error",
          "script_stack" : [
            "doc[date].values + doc[EventT ...",
            "    ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script" : "doc[date].values + doc[EventType].values",
          "lang" : "painless",
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason" : "Variable [date] is not defined."
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

This is one example document.

```
{
  "_index" : "test_4",
  "_type" : "test_4",
  "_id" : "IMQcWGEBOC31Kjf9gyWS",
  "_score" : 18.249443,
  "_source" : {
    "date" : "18-02-02",
    "path" : "/mnt/elk/logstash/data/from/nifi/dev/logs/nifi/nifi-app_2018-02-02_11.0.log",
    "@timestamp" : "2018-02-02T20:01:59.159Z",
    "EventType" : "ERROR",
    "EventText" : "[Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] o.a.n.p.a.storage.PutAzureBlobStorage PutAzureBlobStorage[id=117f16f0-113c-1fcd-6a48-d9d99d3cd288] PutAzureBlobStorage[id=117f16f0-113c-1fcd-6a48-d9d99d3cd288] failed to process due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: IOException thrown from PutAzureBlobStorage[id=117f16f0-113c-1fcd-6a48-d9d99d3cd288]: java.io.IOException; rolling back session: {}",
    "@version" : "1",
    "host" : "hostname",
    "time" : "11:31:36,978",
    "message" : "2018-02-02 11:31:36,978 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] o.a.n.p.a.storage.PutAzureBlobStorage PutAzureBlobStorage[id=117f16f0-113c-1fcd-6a48-d9d99d3cd288] PutAzureBlobStorage[id=117f16f0-113c-1fcd-6a48-d9d99d3cd288] failed to process due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: IOException thrown from PutAzureBlobStorage[id=117f16f0-113c-1fcd-6a48-d9d99d3cd288]: java.io.IOException; rolling back session: {}",
    "type" : "test_4"
  }
},
```

Comment: May you please add your mapping? May you also check for the errors in the logs of elasticsearch? If you do `curl -v` which is the returned http code? Is it 500?

Comment: Nikolay, thanks. added one example document to the post. no errors in elasticsearch logs. curl -v returns "curl: no URL specified!".

Comment: Thanks, of course I meant to add `-v` to the entire command you send: `curl -v -XGET 'http://ip:...`

Comment: If you want to do something like `GROUP BY date, EventType` then you can nest two `terms` aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your interpreter, most likely bash, is removing the `'` from your query. In fact, ES does not receive it:

```
      "script_stack" : [
        "doc[date].values + doc[EventT ...",
        "    ^---- HERE"
      ],
      "script" : "doc[date].values + doc[EventType].values",
```

If you try to `echo` your command you can see that the desired `'` was removed:

```
$ echo curl -XGET 'http://ip:9200/test_4/test_4/_search?pretty=true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
  ...
      "script": "doc['date'].values + doc['EventType'].values",
  ...
}'
curl -XGET http://ip:9200/test_4/test_4/_search?pretty=true -H Content-Type: application/json -d{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
      "script": "doc[date].values + doc[EventType].values",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      ...
```

You should escape the `'` character with a syntax like this `'"'"'`. Here we close the first `'`, start new string with `"`, put the `'`, then close `"` and finally open another `'`. Here is how it will look like altogether:

```
$ echo curl -XGET 'http://ip:9200/test_4/test_4/_search?pretty=true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
      "script": "doc['"'"'date'"'"'].values + doc['"'"'EventType'"'"'].values",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
curl -XGET http://ip:9200/test_4/test_4/_search?pretty=true -H Content-Type: application/json -d{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
      "script": "doc['date'].values + doc['EventType'].values",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can get more information about bash quoting in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834839/how-to-escape-a-double-quote-inside-double-quotes), for example.

I understand you want to find duplicates with `terms` aggregation with values from two fields. The script query you are trying to make won't work because `fielddata` arrays are immutable. This is the script you might use instead:

```
"script": "def l = []; l.addAll(doc['date']); l.addAll(doc['EventType'].values); l",
  "min_doc_count": 2
},
```

You may also consider to use [`copy_to`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_multi_field_terms_aggregation) to copy values from several fields into one and then make regular `terms` aggregation on just one field (this should perform faster than scripted aggregation).

Hope that helps!

Comment: @'Nikolay Vasiliev' thanks, it didn't work, i have edited the post.