# AWK command failing inside nodejs

Tags: node.js, shell, awk, sed, wget

I am trying to run the following command inside child process exec of nodejs and it is failing:

```
wget -qO- some.website | awk -F \"</*TD ALIGN=LEFT>|</*TD>|<*/A>\" \'/<TD ALIGN=LEFT>.*[A-Z]/ {print $12}\' | sed -n 1p
```

I tested the command from a shell script and it runs perfectly. However, when I run it from nodejs it is giving the following error:

```
/bin/sh: TD: No such file or directory
```

Please help.

EDIT:

```
var reportTCC = function() {
     let child = exec(configs.command, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
         if (error !== null) {
             log.error('Error executing the command to retrieve Run Info: ' + error);
             stdout = "UNKNOWN"
         }
         let run_type = stdout;
     });
 };
```

configs.command has the command that I am passing

EDIT2:

```
"command": "ssh -t user@domain 'wget -qO- some.website | awk -F \"</*TD ALIGN=LEFT>|</*TD>|<*/A>\" \"/<TD ALIGN=LEFT>.*[A-Z]/ {print $12}\" | sed -n 1p'",
```

Comment: Must be a quoting issue. Please add the code where you `exec` your command from inside your Nodejs app.

Comment: I made an edit to show how I am using the command.

Comment: We need to see the value of `configs.command` now ^^'

Comment: You're escaping the command, what happens when you won't? 'I tested the command from a shell script and it runs perfectly', I've tested your command in shell, and it doesn't work perfectly with these escape characters, so how did you test?

Comment: I added the escaping just for nodejs. I made edits showing the command in configs.command

Comment: I think you don't need escaping, what happens when you drop them?

Answer (score 1):

Since your escape characters has been passed into `ssh` command, most likely you don't need to escape `awk` arguments. Based on the fact that your ssh is using single quotes such as:

```
ssh -t user@domain 'command to invoke'
```

use double-quotes to wrap your arguments inside these single quotes (so make it consistent, as in your first example you're mixing both). See also: [How to escape a double quote inside double quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3834839/55075)

When you're not sure how the command is invoked, invoke `set -x` shell command to output the tracing messages, or run the command as:

```
ssh -t user@domain bash -x -c 'command to invoke'
```

Another suggestion is not to use `awk` and regular expressions to parse your HTML, but use relevant tools such as: [`pup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup), [`xpup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/xpup) or [`html-xml-utils`](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/README). See: [About parsing html and extract data using shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4994113/55075).