# Replace a variable in a json string with ip address in bash

Tags: bash

Now I have a JSON string in bash:

```
str='{"output_name":"http://HOST:33445/data/results/merged_video.mp4"}'
```

And I got an ip address from a command:

```
HOST_IP_FOR_FUNC="$(minikube ssh "route -n | grep ^0.0.0.0 | awk '{ print \$2 }'")" && echo $HOST_IP_FOR_FUNC
```

The result is `192.168.64.1`.

I'd like to use this variable to replace "HOST" in `str`.

So I used:

```
z=${str//HOST/$HOST_IP_FOR_FUNC} && echo $z
```

only got

```
:33445/data/results/merged_video.mp4"}
```

However, if I explicitly assign a value to the HOST_IP_FOR_FUNC:

```
ip="192.168.64.1"
z=${str//HOST/$ip} && echo $z
```

Then I got what I want:

```
{"output_name":"http://192.168.64.1:33445/data/results/merged_video.mp4"}
```

How can I deal with it?

I am using zsh or bash on MacOS 10.15.3

According to @Cyrus, I got the output of his suggested command:

```
minikube ssh "route -n | grep ^0.0.0.0 | awk '{ print \$2 }'" | hexdump -C

00000000  31 39 32 2e 31 36 38 2e  36 34 2e 31 0d 0a        |192.168.64.1..|
0000000e
```

Comment: It seems that you have some unescaped " symbols in the minikube command. Your `HOST_IP_FOR_FUNC` does not get properly populated. Try to escape i.e. use `\"` for the second and third " in the command.

Comment: Add output of `minikube 'ssh route -n' | grep ^0.0.0.0 | awk '{ print $2 }' | hexdump -C` to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove hex `0d` (carriage return) from string `HOST_IP_FOR_FUNC`:

```
HOST_IP_FOR_FUNC="${HOST_IP_FOR_FUNC/$'\x0d'/}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just glancing at your variable I can tell you it's most likely due to your quotes. You need to escape your inner double quotes. Try this `HOST_IP_FOR_FUNC="$(minikube ssh \x22route -n | grep ^0.0.0.0 | awk '{ print \$2 }'\x22)" && echo $HOST_IP_FOR_FUNC` \x22 being the hex for double quotes. See this post for more details [How to escape a double quote inside double quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834839/how-to-escape-a-double-quote-inside-double-quotes)