# How to put text in quotes? (Get the value of the Set-Cookie header in quotes)

Tags: bash, curl, awk, sed

I have the following command which gives me value of Set-Cookie header:

```
curl --head http://www.stackoverflow.com | sed -n "/^Set-Cookie:/p" | cut -c 13-
```

Output:

> prov=abed7528-7639-e2e3-39a0-361a6d3f7925; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly

I need this output in quotes, like this:

> "prov=abed7528-7639-e2e3-39a0-361a6d3f7925; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly"

Comment: May this question useful for You https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834839/how-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-inside-double-quotes

Comment: Where is the text coming from? A file? A variable? User/tty/pipe input?

Comment: Pipe input and file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using printf

```sh
printf '"%s"\n' "$(curl ...)"
```

Command substitution strips any trailing newlines, so the ending quote will be on the same line.

However, there is a trailing *carriage return* (network traffic generally uses `\r\n` line endings). Add this to the end of the pipeline

```sh
| tr -d '\r'
# or
| sed 's/\r$//'
```

---

Collapsing the pipeline into one sed command:

```sh
curl -s --head http://www.stackoverflow.com | sed -En '/^Set-Cookie:/ {
    s/^.{12}/"/
    s/\r$/"/
    p
    q
}'
```

Comment: OK, but it adds double quotes twice "" I only need one" )

Comment: Works for me. Show exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Great, the latter works the way I needed

Comment: Show the code you ran to produce that output.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a single line, piping it into `sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/'` should do the trick.

If your text spans multiple lines, this won’t do, but the following would work:

```
… | { printf \"; cat; echo \"; }
```

… however, this will preserve all newlines, which might also not be desirable. To suppress the very last newline, use the following instead:

```
… | { printf \"; sed '$s/$/"/'; }
```

Or, as a single `sed` command:

```
… | sed '1s/^/"/; $s/$/"/'
```

Comment: It adds the last quotes to the new line, is it possible to add it to the last line?

Comment: `printf` is more portable than `echo -n`.

Comment: @Rauf That’s addressed in the second part of the answer, isn’t it?

Comment: @Barmar Oh, I wasn’t aware (or more likely, forgot) that the `-n` flag wasn’t portable. POSIX never ceases to surprise. I’ll change it.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question here, I edited it. I hope this is correct now.

Comment: @Rauf Yes, the question is fine now. My solution *should* work with this, I honestly don’t know why it doesn’t.