# Bash double quotes inside double quotes BSD

Tags: bash, rsync, bsd

Similar thread:

[How can I escape a double quote inside double quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834839/how-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-inside-double-quotes)

I have a freebsd box with GNU bash, version 4.4.0(0)-release.

On this box there is a shell script running rsync, this script needs to specify an rsync path parameter which has space inside it.

`dqt='"'`

`RSYNC="/usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn --rsync-path=${dqt}sudo rsync${dqt}"`

The interpreter is bash but just to make sure I have tried it with specifically bash -x and here is what I get:

`+ /usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn '--rsync-path="sudo' 'rsync"' --numeric-ids --delete ...`

Which of course going to lead to rsync error: syntax or usage error.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Run rsync fine as:

`rsync-path="sudo rsync"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rsync command seems to have been word-split. You can't store a full command in a variable, you have to use an array:

```sh
RSYNC_ARR=( /usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn --rsync-path="sudo rsync" )

"${RSYNC_ARR[@]}" # the double quotes are mandatory here
```

A little test to see the difference:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

RSYNC='/usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn --rsync-path="sudo rsync"'

RSYNC_ARR=( /usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn --rsync-path=sudo\ rsync )

set -x

: $RSYNC
#+ : /usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn '--rsync-path="sudo' 'rsync"'

: ${RSYNC_ARR[@]}
#+ : /usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn --rsync-path=sudo rsync

: "$RSYNC"
#+ : '/usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn --rsync-path="sudo rsync"'

: "${RSYNC_ARR[@]}"
#+ : /usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn '--rsync-path=sudo rsync'
```

Comment: This is still not good, this will produce:  /usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn --rsync-path=sudo rsync --numeric-ids so as you see the " missing again and it will break

Comment: That printf will output /usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn --rsync-path=sudo\ rsync which is still not good, breaks the script

Comment: If it breaks then that means that you're using your `$RSYNC` variable in a context that I cannot guess. WHERE and HOW are you using your `$RSYNC` variable?

Comment: This worked the RSYNC_ARR and using, quoted "${RSYNC_ARR[@]}" afterwards, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the quoting from double quoted to single quoted, like:

```
RSYNC="/usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn --rsync-path="'"sudo rsync"'
```

I've used this in a small bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

RSYNC="/usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn --rsync-path="'"sudo rsync"'
echo "#" $RSYNC "#"

eval "$RSYNC"
```

with the result:

```
+ RSYNC='/usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn --rsync-path="sudo rsync"'
+ echo '#' /usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn '--rsync-path="sudo' 'rsync"' '#'
# /usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn --rsync-path="sudo rsync" #
+ eval '/usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn --rsync-path="sudo rsync"'
++ /usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn '--rsync-path=sudo rsync'
./x: line 6: /usr/local/bin/rsync: No such file or directory
```

OK, I don't have an rsync in /usr/local bin, but you can see that the last argument, `--rsync-path=sudo rsync` is enclosed in single quotes and thus a single arument,

Comment: This is not even close. It will produce  '--rsync-path="sudo' 'rsync"' I have messed around with these "' combinations already

Comment: No, regardless your suggestion this does not work. I get: /usr/local/bin/rsync -avzn '--rsync-path="sudo' 'rsync"' --numeric-ids