# How to escape single and double quotes in Bash

Tags: bash, escaping, quotes, double-quotes, single-quotes

I have a script that takes text as an argument and encodes it. If the text contains only single quotes I surround it with double and vice versa, but it gets tricky if it contains both because it will be closed at first appearance.

```
script "I can't use "test" text"
// Double quote will be terminated at "I can't use "
```

So how can I escape both cases without using a backslash, like in Python using triple single, or double quotes.

```
script '''I can't use "test" text'''
// or
script """I can't use "test" text"""
```

Comment: There's nothing like triple quotes or raw strings in bash. Why without using backslash?

Comment: I may pass huge text which I will copy/paste from somewhere. And adding backslashes to every quote isn't easy.

Comment: So read the text from stdin rather than making it an argument.

Comment: you could put it in a file.

Comment: The following isn't the most practical solution, so I don't want to submit it as an answer.  But you could parse the text and have it add a backslash to escape any quote.

Comment: I cannot reproduce `"I can't use "test" text"` is not "terminating double quotes", it is a single argument. Please post how are you checking it?

Comment: @KamilCuk If you type `echo "I can't use "test" text"` you won't see the quotes around `test`

Comment: Okay, I was hoping there is a way to do it with arguments but I will use alternative methods. Thanks.

Comment: Canonical questions: *[How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/)* (2009. 26 answers. 1380 votes) and *[How can I escape a double quote inside double quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834839/how-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-inside-double-quotes)*

Comment: Why isn't there *any* attempt to find the duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a here-document, and use command subsitution to turn it into an argument.

```
script "$(cat <<'EOF'
I can't use "test" text
EOF)"
```

Or