# not able escape single quotes (') while using sed command

Tags: sed

while using,

```
sed -i '122 i <button type="button" onclick="window.open('https://localhost:$ctrl','_blank')">CTRL01</button>' SCP_PortForwarding.html;
```

in SCP_PortForwarding.html i am getting,

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.open(https://localhost:10941,_blank)">CTRL01</button>
```

but want to print,

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('https://localhost:10941','_blank')">CTRL01</button>
```

where $ctrl is randomly assigned port number.

Comment: You can't include single-quotes or variable references in a single-quoted string.

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes, you can. See [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834839)

Comment: @Bohemian That's about double-quoted strings (where you can include double-quotes by escaping them). There's a linked question [about single-quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings), but the only answers there boil down to "end the single-quoted string, then use some other quoting/escaping mode to add a literal single-quote".

Comment: @GordonDavisson one of the answers shows how to deal with both quotes within quotes and apostrophes within apostrophes. I actually used that answer yesterday myself for just such a situation (for an alias def)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `sed`

```
$ sed -i "122 i <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"window.open('https://localhost:$ctrl','_blank')\">CTRL01</button>" SCP_PortForwarding.html
```