# Extra character after close-quote

Tags: bash, shell, tcl, cadence

I am running the below command in MATLAB. This code is basically launching cadence xcelium simulator in gui mode using the command *nclaunch*.  nclaunch opens the xterm and from there it should launch xcelium simulator but befor that I am getting the error.

```
tclcmds = {  'exec xmvhdl -64bit osc_filter.vhd simple_osc.vhd osc_top.vhd',...
             'exec xmelab -64bit -access +wc osc_top',...
             ['hdlsimmatlab -gui osc_top -64bit ', ...
              ' -input "{@matlabcp :u_osc_filter -mfunc oscfilter}"',...
              ' -input "{@force clk_enable {"1"} -after 0ns}"',...
              ' -input "{@force reset {"0"} -after 0ns {"1"} -after 40ns {"0"} -after 120ns}"',...
              ' -input "{@force clk {"1"} -after 0ns {"0"} -after 40ns -repeat 80ns}"',...
              ' -input "{@simvision  {set w \[waveform new\]}}"',...
              ' -input "{@simvision  {waveform add -using \$w -signals :clk_enable}}"',...
              ' -input "{@simvision  {waveform add -using \$w -signals :clk}}"',...
              ' -input "{@simvision  {waveform add -using \$w -signals :reset}}"',...
              ' -input "{@simvision  {waveform add -using \$w -signals signed(:osc_out)}}"',...
              ' -input "{@simvision  {waveform add -using \$w -signals signed(:filter8x_out)}}"',...
              ' -input "{@simvision  {waveform format -using \$w signed(:osc_out) -trace analogSampleAndHold}}"',...
              ' -input "{@simvision  {waveform format -using \$w signed(:filter8x_out) -trace analogSampleAndHold}}"',...
              ' -input "{@simvision  {waveform axis range -min -50000 -max 50000 -using \$w signed(:osc_out)}}"',...
              ' -input "{@simvision  {waveform axis range -min -1.5e6 -max 1.5e6 -using \$w signed(:filter8x_out)}}"',...  
              ' -input "{@database -open waves -into waves.shm -default}"',...
              ' -input "{@probe -create -shm :clk_enable :clk :reset :osc_out :filter8x_out}"',...
              ' -input "{@run 10000ns}"'
             ]};
nclaunch('tclstart',tclcmds);
```

After running above command I am getting following error
`extra characters after close-quote`

I am not sure about this error.

Comment: Without being able to (clearly) see what Tcl is being told to run, it's going to be hard to diagnose this

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Why is this tagged _bash_ and _shell_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the double quotes in these strings are not interpreted the way you expect:

```
' -input "{@force clk_enable {"1"} -after 0ns}"',...
' -input "{@force reset {"0"} -after 0ns {"1"} -after 40ns {"0"} -after 120ns}"',...
' -input "{@force clk {"1"} -after 0ns {"0"} -after 40ns -repeat 80ns}"',...
```

Fore example the first string probably gets interpreted as following parts:

- -input
- " - open-quote
- {@force clk_enable { - a string in quotes
- " - close-quote
- 1"} -after 0ns}" - extra characters after close-quote

I would suggest trying to:

- remove those string to make sure the error disappears
- trying to escape the quotes - probably instead of {"1"} typing {\"1\"} or something similar, see this question for discussion [How can I escape a double quote inside double quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834839/how-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-inside-double-quotes)