# bash: 'map' function arguments?

Tags: bash, xargs

What is the most elegant way to essentially 'map' a list of bash arguments through some transformation (such as concatenating each string) before forwarding the list onto some other command? Using `xargs` comes to mind but I can't seem to conceptualize how to do this.

```
function do_something {
    # hypothetically
    for arg in "$@"; do
        arg="$arg.txt"
    done

    command "$@"
}

do_something file1 file2 file3
```

Such that the result would be to call `command file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've done is mostly correct, except that you'll need to use an array to store the new arguments:

```
function do_something {
    array=()
    for arg in "$@"; do
        array+=("$arg.txt")
    done

    command "${array[@]}"
}

do_something file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: Awesome. This is definitely more readable (and elegant) than string operations shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3104637/1641160)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following definition for a `map` that is similar to the one found in many functional programming languages (eg [python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map)):

```
function map
{
    local f="$1"
    shift # consume first argument
    for arg
    do
        "$f" "$arg" # assuming `f` prints a single line per call
    done
}
```

Here's how you would use it in your example. Here `some_cmd` may be a function defined locally:

```
function do_something
{
    local IFS=$'\n' # only split on newlines when word splitting
    result=($(map suffix "$@")) # split into lines and store into array
    some_cmd "${result[@]}" # call some_cmd with mapped arguments.
}
function suffix
{
    echo "$@".txt
}

do_something file1 file2 file3
```

Here's another variation of writing `do_something`. Here `some_cmd` must exist in `$PATH`:

```
function do_something
{
    map suffix "$@" | xargs some_cmd # call some_cmd with mapped arguments. 
}
```

The main downside is that to use the result in another function, you need to mess around with `IFS` to split on the newlines, or pipe into xargs; and if your map outputs contain newlines then either method fails completely.

Comment: True, I chose a poor placeholder name.

Answer (score 0):

In order to "forward" arguments to other commands, there are several ways. Try this script:

```
printargs() {
  echo "Args for $1:"
  shift
  for a in "$@"; do
   echo "    arg: -$a-"
  done
}

printargs dolstar $*
printargs dolstarquot "$*"
printargs dolat $@
printargs dolatquot "$@"
```

and invoke it with test aguments:

> ./sc.sh 1 2 3
>   Args for dolstar:
>       arg: -1-
>       arg: -2-
>       arg: -3-
>   Args for dolstarquot:
>       arg: -1 2 3-
>   Args for dolat:
>       arg: -1-
>       arg: -2-
>       arg: -3-
>   Args for dolatquot:
>       arg: -1-
>       arg: -2-
>       arg: -3-

Things go a little differently if an argument contains spaces:

> ./sc.sh 1 "2 3"
>   Args for dolstar:
>       arg: -1-
>       arg: -2-
>       arg: -3-
>   Args for dolstarquot:
>       arg: -1 2 3-
>   Args for dolat:
>       arg: -1-
>       arg: -2-
>       arg: -3-
>   Args for dolatquot:
>       arg: -1-
>       arg: -2 3-

The *dolatquot* "$@" is the only version that correctly forwards arguments. Otherwise, as seen in another answer, you can manipulate arguments and construct a new list via arrays or a single string.