# Invalid behavior for arguments in Bash version 4.4 vs version 5.1?

Tags: bash, shell

I am confused with this behavior, I have the following script:

`backup.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash -x

set -e

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo 'No arguments passed'
    exit 1
fi

# Get the arguments
for ARGUMENT in "$@"; do
  KEY=$(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f1 -d=)
  VALUE=$(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f2 -d=)

  case "$KEY" in
  backup_dir) BACKUP_DIR=${VALUE} ;;
  postgres_dbs) POSTGRES_DBS=${VALUE} ;;
  backup_name) BACKUP_NAME=${VALUE} ;;
  postgres_port) POSTGRES_PORT=${VALUE} ;;
  postgres_host) POSTGRES_HOST=${VALUE} ;;
  *) ;;
  esac
done
```

And I am executing it using:

1.

```
/bin/bash -c /usr/bin/backup.sh postgres_dbs=grafana,keycloak backup_name=postgres-component-test-20220210.165630 backup_dir=/backups/postgres postgres_port=5432 postgres_host=postgres.default.svc.cluster.local
```

2. 

```
/usr/bin/backup.sh postgres_dbs=grafana,keycloak backup_name=postgres-component-test-20220210.165630 backup_dir=/backups/postgres postgres_port=5432 postgres_host=postgres.default.svc.cluster.local
```

But the output is:

```
+ set -e
+ [[ 0 -eq 0 ]]
+ echo 'No arguments passed'
No arguments passed
+ exit 1
```

Environment:

```
# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Bash version where I can reproduce this issue:

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

However, this is not happening in the Bash version:

```
GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0)
```

Comment: Are you **sure** this is reproducible with the second form, `/usr/bin/backup.sh postgres...`, without `/bin/bash -c` at the front?

Comment: @JohnKugelman it is, I added the docker image and the steps where I can reproduce it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't seem to use the Bash "-c" option with arguments after the "-c" option string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711970/i-cant-seem-to-use-the-bash-c-option-with-arguments-after-the-c-option-st)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem using that Docker image and running `./backup.sh foo bar baz`: the script gets 3 arguments, as expected.

Comment: I *can* reproduce it by running `bash -c ./backup.sh foo bar baz`: the script gets 0 arguments. But that's expected.

Comment: @Deathgrip The question title is a perfect match, but unfortunately the question and answers don't really apply here. In that question the poster misused double quotes.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - I beg to differ. The issue is related to how `bash -c` processes the command and arguments afterwards. Here, @Vishrant is not using either when the command should probably be `/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/backup.sh postgres_dbs=grafana,keycloak backup_name=postgres-component-test-20220210.165630 backup_dir=/backups/postgres postgres_port=5432 postgres_host=postgres.default.svc.cluster.local"`

Comment: I can reproduce this exact behavior on `GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` looking at the man page this seems to be the intended behavior of `-c` option - the arguments do not belong to the script, but to the shell. Why are you running the script with `bash -c` if it already has a shabang line?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I tried `./backup.sh arguments` here is the pastebin https://pastebin.com/k0C99PWp still I can reproduce the issue

Comment: Did you notice in the pastebin you have an error - you typed `0` instead of `$#` so the condition is always true!

Comment: @Vishrant, that pastebin is not equivalent to the script presented in the question.  Its literal `if [[ 0 -eq 0 ]]` will always evaluate to true.

Comment: I didn't realize the `cat << EOF > backup.sh` rendered the env variables.

Comment: Well, it does, @Vishrant.  The contents of a heredoc are subject to parameter and other expansions, *unless* any part of the terminator token is quoted (in the redirection operator; it must not be quoted at the end of the heredoc).

Comment: You guys are correct, it's a feature and not a bug, the script is missing the argument when I am running with `-C` and it works when I am removing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug, just a feature!

When you use the `bash -c 'code …'` style, actually the first CLI argument is passed to the inline code as `$0`, not `$1`.

Furthermore, if the `'code …'` itself invokes an external script such as `./script.sh`, then you should not forget to pass the arguments using the `"$@"` construct.

So you could just write (as pointed out in the comments):

```sh
bash -c './script.sh "$@"' bash "first argument"
```

Or most succinctly, just like you mention you had already tried:

```sh
bash script.sh "first argument"
```

#### Additional notes

As your example was not really "minimal" (it had a very long command-line), here is a complete minimal example that you might want to test for debugging purpose:

> script.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "\$#: $#"
for arg; do printf -- '- %s\n' "$arg"; done
```

Then you should get a session similar to:

```sh
$ chmod a+x script.sh

$ bash -c ./script.sh "arg 1" "arg 2"
$#: 0

$ bash -c './script.sh "$@"' "arg 1" "arg 2"
$#: 1
- arg 2

$ bash -c './script.sh "$@"' bash "arg 1" "arg 2"
$#: 2
- arg 1
- arg 2

$ bash script.sh "arg 1" "arg 2"
$#: 2
- arg 1
- arg 2

$ ./script.sh "arg 1" "arg 2"
$#: 2
- arg 1
- arg 2
```

Comment: Please check the question, I have already tried what you are suggesting, I thought adding double quotes will fix it, but it does not.

Comment: I checked the question, and I can reproduce the issue **only** with `/bin/bash -c /usr/bin/backup.sh postgres_dbs=…`, while with `/usr/bin/backup.sh postgres_dbs=…` I get `…
+ [[ 1 -eq 0 ]] …`, hence my answer…

Comment: Are you using the same environment that I posted? I can not reproduce it in the Bash 5.1.8, same script, same command.

Comment: Hi @Vishrant, to sum up: the issue I mentioned in my answer **does take place** (your commands 1. and 2. are **not equivalent** and I can reproduce a difference with "GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"); admittedly, you might also experience another, bash-version-specific issue, but could you confirm whether you also get a different outcome between your commands 1. and 2. as I explained in my answer?

Comment: I updated the questions with the steps to reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKugelman for your remarks… so I fixed the answer accordingly. But, I'm puzzled the OP can't reproduce our suggestions alike…

Answer (score 3):

You wrote two ways to invoke the script, which boil down to:

1. `bash -c ./script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3`
2. `./script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3`

The second way is the preferred way to invoke scripts. Running them directly tells Linux to use the interpreter listed in the shebang line. There's no reason I can see for this invocation style to drop arguments.

The first, however, does indeed lose all the arguments. It's because `-c` doesn't belong there. If you want to invoke an explicit `bash` shell you should write simply:

```
bash ./script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

That will correctly pass all the arguments to the script.

When you add `-c` it turns `./script.sh` from the name of a script into a full blown command line. What's the difference? Well, now that command line is responsible for forwarding its arguments to the script, if that's what it wants to have happen. With `-c` you need to explicitly pass them on:

```
bash -c './script.sh "$@"' bash arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Yuck! It's encased in single quotes, and there's an ugly `"$@"` in there. It's needed, though. Without `"$@"` the arguments are simply dropped on the floor.

`-c` also takes an extra argument, the value for `$0`. So not only is `"$@"` needed, you also have to add an extra `bash` argument to set `$0`. (`bash` is a good choice since that's what `$0` is normally set to when running a bash script.)