# Passing argument with spaces to Spring batch CommandLineJobRunner

Tags: spring, command-line, spring-batch

In configuring the spring batch jobs, I have a need to pass argument to CommandLineJobRunner which have spaces.

**For example :**

```
java -cp "../../myproject.jar" org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner jobconf.xml readJob -comp.name=My Company
```

When executing the above Job, Spring Batch is getting the `comp.name` value as "My" only.

How to get the `full name("My Company")` including the `spaces`?

Any suggestions will be of great help!

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try with form `"-comp.name=My Company"`?

Answer (score 0):

Argument having spaces in it splitted into multiple arguments. Use quotes to specify it as a single argument.
May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619831/issue-with-command-line-arguments-which-got-spaces-in-it) can help you

Comment: Even if the arg is passed with double quotes "My Company", the Job is not getting the full value.