# Java: How to accept args inputs with spaces in-between

Tags: java, output, args

If I were to run my code using `java example hello 3` the output would be `hello 3`

However, if I want to run `java example hello world 3` the output would be `hello world` not `hello world 3`

How would I fix this?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        String t = args[1];
        int s = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println(t)
        System.out.println(s)
```

Comment: have you actually run your program on those inputs with those results? The code you've posted doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17619865/6590339

You can use quotes when you want an argument to have a space in it:

`$java example "hello 3"`

Comment: it looks like this method doesn't include spaces in the output e.g.$java example "hello 3" returns "hello3"

Comment: I think there are some other issues in your method. If, you only care about the first argument, then I would just have `String t = args[0]` and `System.out.println(t)`. There is no need to use `Integer.parseInt` if you are just printing to the command line