# How can I read the console arguments separated by line instead of spaces in java?

Tags: java, console-application

I have a console application where I need to read the console inputs as separated by line instead of separated by spaces. Is this possible?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Here the args is a string array and each console input separated by a space will be a separate member in args[]. I need to avoid this. For example , if the input is

```
word1 word2
line2
line3
```

i need to read it as

```
args[0] = word1 word2
args[1] = line2
args[2] = line3
```

Comment: A question very similar to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743454/space-in-java-command-line-arguments

Answer (score 0):

After the first line the input becomes part of stdin. You could read remaining lines using Java's Scanner api

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

See [Some detailed examples](http://webclass.superquest.net/apjava/JavaNotes%20Reference/notes-java-2006-04-12/notes-java/examples-introductory/console/console-input-scanner.html)  or SO question [How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-to-use-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Using this, you could re-create arguments and pass it to a another method.